# Cucumber: How do I enable a hook with a command line parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have this hook here:
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.try(:status) == :failed
    @fail_count = @fail_count.to_i + 1
    save_and_open_page if @fail_count <= 5
  end

but I don't want it to always open failed scenarios.

Is there a way I can set up my cucumber such that when I do `cucumber vars ... enable_open_page` the above hook enables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
After do |scenario| 
  if scenario.try(:status) == :failed 
    @fail_count = @fail_count.to_i + 1 
    save_and_open_page if ENV["ENABLE_OPEN_PAGE"].present? and @fail_count <= 5 
  end
end
```

And call cucumber with the environment variable:

```
ENABLE_OPEN_PAGE=true cucumber
```